# What is the advantage of using std::type_info::hash_code over std::type_index

Tags: c++, typeid

Is the only difference that one can be used as an index?

What is the advantage of using one over the other to compare types?

Answer (score 0):

`std::type_info::hash_code()` is a member function that returns a `std::size_t`. It's just a number, you can't get the `name` of the `std::type_info` from it.

`std::type_index` is a type compatible with containers, that also has a `name` member, referring back to the `std::type_info` that it indexes.

Answer (score 0):

As with any hash, *collisions are possible*:

> Returns an unspecified value such that for all `type_info` objects referring to the same type, their `hash_code()` is the same.
>
> No other guarantees are given: `type_info` objects referring to different types may have the same `hash_code` (although the standard recommends that implementations avoid this as much as possible), and `hash_code` for the same type can change between invocations of the same program.

*([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code))*

(That last phrase is particularly interesting.)

Which of the two functions you want to use depends on what you're trying to do. Generally, `type_index()` is what you're looking for. It uniquely identifies a type. If you want a key for an associative container, `type_index()`'s hasher effectively *is* `hash_code()`.

I can't think of a reason why you'd ever need to use `hash_code()` yourself unless you're for some reason trying to avoid `type_index()` (or you find you need to specify the hasher yourself), though the linked article has an example of such an implementation.